# Assigning more than one Modifier Keys to a Key Gesture SHIFT + F not supported

Tags: c#, wpf, keyboard-shortcuts

I have the following code:

```
MyPlayPause.InputGestures.Add(new KeyGesture(Key.P, ModifierKeys.Control));
```

I need to add another gesure SO I CAN HAVE SHIFT + CTRL + P but it breaks when i add the option for:

```
MyPlayPause.InputGestures.Add(new KeyGesture(Key.P, ModifierKeys.Control));
```

shift option. I get this error: `'Shift+F' key and modifier combination is not supported for KeyGesture.`

Any idea why? I need to replicate the functionality of the Media Player fast forward button.

Comment: oops fixed by looking at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/66674894-720c-4c04-98e8-e48f741f03c1

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`ModifierKeys` enum is a marked as `[FlagsAttribute]` so you can do:

```
ModifierKeys.Control | ModifierKeys.Shift
```

So:

```
MyPlayPause.InputGestures.Add(new KeyGesture(Key.P, ModifierKeys.Control |  ModifierKeys.Shift));
```

Comment: Yes, but if I use 'Key.D0' and `ModifierKeys.Control | ModifierKeys.None` to get bind a digit key to a command, the shortcut only works when Control is pressed, and this is supposed to be `None` **AND OR** 'Control`.